# In Stargate: Atlantis, How are they able to disconnect the ZPM despite being under water?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

I am watching *Stargate: Atlantis* episode "Critical Mass" (S2E13). In this episode a bomb is placed on Atlantis and is set to go off should someone dial the gate back to Earth, which they do once a month.

Once they find out-as a way to prevent someone from dialing back to Earth and intentionally triggering the bomb-they entirely disconnect the ZPM, the only power source capable of doing so.

The problem with this is that they established earlier in the series that the ZPM is the only way they are able to maintain shields and submerge the city under the water safely. At the time the city was submerged as a way to fool the Wraith into thinking Atlantis was destroyed, so they very much needed the ZPM power to maintain the shields in that episode.

How is it possible that the ZPM was disconnected and Atlantis was still able to remain hidden under the water?

Comment: The city was cloaked not submerged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, my mistake. This episode apparently took place before Atlantis was submerged. So there was no dilema to begin with.

Comment: you can delete your question in order not to appear anymore.

Comment: @Shade Thanks, seemed to make sense to keep it in case anyone made the same mistake I did and was curious as to the answer.

Comment: I'd agree if it were a question based on a real case but it is based on an error. So, the probability of someone having the same question is IMHO rather small.

Comment: @Shade I tried to delete it, said I dont have permission to.